# Modelling probabilties within friend sets

Tags: probability, modeling, binomial-distribution, model

Recently, I was wondering about calculating the probability of a given individual in a given population "knowing" (let's say, present in individual's friend set) at least one person with a given trait A and at least one person with another given trait, B; where it is possible that any number of people in the given individual's friend set can possess both traits.

For example, using genetic traits, in a given population, how could one calculate the probability that a given individual in a given population "knows" at least one person with grey eye colour and at least one person who is greater than 200cm tall; where, naturally, it is possible that any number of people in the friend set can possess grey eye colour *and* be greater than 200cm tall.

I have developed a sort of model, but it may not be correctly specified; it is as follows:

**Assumptions and Qualifications:**

- First of all, for simplicity, let's assume that we define "knowing" as mutually connected friends on an online social network.
- Secondly, the frequencies of genetic traits are (a) going to be determined by ethnicity of a given population as well as environmental factors (nutrition, healthcare) and (b) unlikely to be independently distributed across a given individual's friend set (e.g. family members will have greater genetic similarity); however, for this problem, let's adopt a simple model where both of the above conditions are violated.
- Thirdly, assume that the individual's friend set provides a microcosmic representation of society; this facilitates a frequentist generation of probabilities from the instance rate in the population.
- Finally, instances of genetic traits in the population are fabricated, but are used to generate probabilities for the examples.

**Model Formulation:**

I have reasoned that a binomial random distribution can be applied to the probability of each genetic trait, where a "success" is defined as an individual in the friend set possessing that genetic trait.

Thus for trait A, we have:

$$P(A=k) = \binom{N}{k}p_{a}^{k}(1-p_{a})^{N-k}$$

and, for trait B:

$$P(B=k) = \binom{N}{k}p_{b}^{k}(1-p_{b})^{N-k}$$

where $N$ is number of friends in the friend set, $k$ is number of people containing the genetic trait and $p_{x}$ is the probability associated with possessing genetic trait $X$.

Because the scenario is concerned with the probability of *at least one* person possessing trait A and *at least one* person possessing trait B, it is easier to find the complement of no people in a friend set containing the trait; for both traits:

$$P(A >= 1) = 1 - P(A = 0)$$

and

$$P(B >= 1) = 1 - P(B = 0)$$

Furthermore, we know that probability of an intersection of events is given by:

$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A|B)\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(B|A)\mathbb{P}(A)$$

However, because we are assuming independence between genetic traits, $\mathbb{P}(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)$ are independent, thus:

$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$$

Combining the information above, we get the following model for the above scenario:

$$\mathbb{P}(A >=1, B >=1) = \left(1-\binom{N}{k}p_{a}^{k}(1-p_{a})^{N-k}\right)\left(1-\binom{N}{k}p_{b}^{k}(1-p_{b})^{N-k}\right)$$

So, for the original example above, assuming a friend set of size $N = 300$, the instance of trait A in the population is $\frac{1}{800}$ and the instance of trait B in the population is $\frac{1}{5000}$; according to the model, we get the final probability:

$$\mathbb{P}(A >=1, B >=1)$$

$$ = \left(1-\binom{300}{0}\left(\frac{1}{800}\right)^{0}\left(\frac{799}{800}\right)^{300}\right)\left(1-\binom{300}{0}\left(\frac{1}{5000}\right)^{0}\left(\frac{4999}{5000}\right)^{300}\right)$$

$$\approx 0.018 = 1.8\%$$

Does this model seem reasonable given the assumptions?

Assuming this model is *not* correctly specified, maybe somebody could provide a more accurate representation.